# How do I utilize the value change listener in a Vaadin grid?

Tags: java, event-handling, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm using `Vaadin 8.0.0.beta1`.  I have a `Grid` and within it, I want to tap into the `ValueChangeListener`.  Once the event fires for the edited cell, I need to run some code.

Anyway, I have the following set:

```
grid.setEditorEnabled(true);
grid.getColumn("commentsColumn")
            .setEditorField(new TextArea())
            .getEditorField()
            .addValueChangeListener(event -> Notification.show("BLAH"));
```

Just a test, I expected the comments column to first of all, look like a TextArea field.  Second, fire a notification once the text was change.

Neither appear to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Notifications.showSuccess("BLAH"); or is it Notification.show()???

Comment: `Notifications.showSuccess(..)` is just a wrapper I did for success messages.  I changed my question to possibly avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The code you provided is working as it is, without any changes.
Dummy data was taken from the official Vaadin Grid documentation example.
What I did was just double-click the column.